# Assigning a variable name from Key with value as Value from multidimensional array (from json)

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm sure there's a simple answer, but I've been searching stackoverflow and trying new things for a couple hours and can't seem to figure this out. Any help appreciated!

I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "key":"user_agent",
      "value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
   },
   {  
      "key":"language",
      "value":"en-US"
   }
]
```

For the future, this json object may change, have more key/value pairs, change order of key etc.

In PHP, I want to assign a $variableName for each "key" and assign the value as the "value".

Here's what I've got so far:

```
$arrayDecode = json_decode($data["someArray"]);

//count how many THIS WORKS
$iterations = count($arrayDecode, COUNT_RECURSIVE);

//loop DOES NOT WORK
for($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
    $currentVariableName = $arrayDecode[$i]->key;
    $currentVariableName = $arrayDecode[$i]->value;
}
```

I've tried something like ${"variable$i"}. Also tried using Foreach and the extract function. Any suggestions greatly appreciated, I'm tired and want to move on from this problem which probably has an obvious solution to someone who knows PHP more than I do!

So to be clear, given the above the outcome would be

```
$user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 ...."
$language = "en-US"
```

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear, What I would like is to create a PHP $variable ($key) and assign a value ($value) from a multi-dimensional array. So in the above: $user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0...."    and    $language = "en-US"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arrayDecode = '[  
   {  
      "key":"user_agent",
      "value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
   },
   {  
      "key":"language",
      "value":"en-US"
   }
]';
```

Can do it with foreach and key value

```
$arrayDecode = json_decode($arrayDecode);

$collection = array();

if($arrayDecode){
    foreach($arrayDecode as $v){
        $collection[$v->key] = $v->value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew there would be an easy solution I don't know about, thanks for teaching me. This solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `json_decode()` and simple `foreach()` for that in order to fetch each key and value:

```
<?php
    $json = '[  
        {  
           "key":"user_agent",
           "value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
        },
        {  
           "key":"language",
           "value":"en-US"
        }
     ]';
    $arr = json_decode($json,true);
    $final = array();
    foreach($arr as $sub){
        $final[$sub['key']] = $sub['value'];
    }
    print_r($final);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
    [language] => en-US
)
```

If you are expecting more than one pair which contains same key name (two `user_agent` for exam), then you must create multi-dimensional array:

```
    <?php
        $json = '[  
            {  
               "key":"user_agent",
               "value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
            },
            {  
               "key":"language",
               "value":"en-US"
            }
         ]';
        $arr = json_decode($json,true);
        $final = array();
        foreach($arr as $key => $sub){
            $final[$key][$sub['key']] = $sub['value'];
        }
        print_r($final);
    ?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [language] => en-US
        )

)
```

UPDATE:
In order to have keys as variables, you can add following into foreach loop:

```
$$sub['key'] = $sub['value'];
```

Comment: And then on an associative array you can use [PHP extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function in order to transform them in simple variable names like author wanted